# Что означает «более 20 чего-либо»?

Tags: значение-слов, числительные

Скажите, что означает «более 20»? Включается ли само число 20, или нет, в понятие «более 20»? Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь скорее вопрос из области математики, но все же отвечу: нет, число **20** не включается в данное ***строгое неравенство***, т.к. **"более 20"** — текстовая запись выражения **"> 20"** (а не **"⩾ 20"**).

Если вам необходимо построить фразу, которая будет включать само число **20**, можно использовать один из двух вариантов: **"20 или более"** или **"не менее 20"**.
Оба эти варианта допустимы: первый чуть легче для быстрого понимания сути, второй выглядит немного элегантнее, но чуть сложнее воспринимается людьми, далекими от математики.